# Where to set SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole LANDINGPAGE=Billing

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I read lots of post here about setting SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole LANDINGPAGE=Billing parameter in SetExpressCheckout to force Paypal showing customer guest checkout in Magento. But I am not sure where to set it. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

That would be in the actual API request for SetExpressCheckout.  Here's a sample SEC request that includes those parameters:

```
[REQUESTDATA] => Array
    (
        [USER] => sandbo_1215254764_biz_api1.angelleye.com
        [PWD] => 1215254774
        [VERSION] => 97.0
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => AngellEYE_PHPClass
        [SIGNATURE] => AiKZhEEPLJjSIccz.2M.tbyW5YFwAb6E3l6my.pY9br1z2qxKx96W18v
        [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
        [MAXAMT] => 200.00
        [RETURNURL] => http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/standard/samples/DoExpressCheckoutPayment.php
        [CANCELURL] => http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/paypal/class/cancel.php
        [REQCONFIRMSHIPPING] => 0
        [NOSHIPPING] => 1
        [ALLOWNOTE] => 1
        [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Sole
        [LANDINGPAGE] => Billing
        [BRANDNAME] => Angell EYE
        [CUSTOMERSERVICENUMBER] => 555-555-5555
        [GIFTMESSAGEENABLE] => 1
        [GIFTRECEIPTENABLE] => 1
        [GIFTWRAPENABLE] => 1
        [GIFTWRAPNAME] => Box with Ribbon
        [GIFTWRAPAMOUNT] => 2.50
        [BUYEREMAILOPTIONENABLE] => 1
        [SURVEYENABLE] => 1
        [BUYERREGISTRATIONDATE] => 2012-07-14T00:00:00Z
        [L_BILLINGTYPE0] => MerchantInitiatedBilling
        [L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0] => Billing Agreement
        [L_PAYMENTTYPE0] => Any
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 100.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 80.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 15.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 5.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC] => This is a test order.
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTETEXT] => This is a test note before ever having left the web site.
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Widget 123
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => Widget 123
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 40.00
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => 123
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMURL0] => http://www.angelleye.com/products/123.php
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1] => Widget 456
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1] => Widget 456
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1] => 40.00
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1] => 456
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1] => 1
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMURL1] => http://www.angelleye.com/products/456.php
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY1] => Digital
    )
```

Comment: But where to set it in Magento?

Comment: In the PayPal class where the request is getting generated.  You'll need to write an extension.

Answer (score 0):

.../app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php

Example:

```
     /**
     * SetExpressCheckout call
     * @link https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout
     * TODO: put together style and giropay settings
     */
    public function callSetExpressCheckout()
    {
        $this->_prepareExpressCheckoutCallRequest($this->_setExpressCheckoutRequest);
        $request = $this->_exportToRequest($this->_setExpressCheckoutRequest);
        $this->_exportLineItems($request);

        $request['LANDINGPAGE'] = 'Billing'; //HERE

        // import/suppress shipping address, if any
        $options = $this->getShippingOptions();
```